# Есть ли в русском языке слово "сипся"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Скажите, пожалуйста, если кто знает? Есть ли в русском языке слово "сипся"? Ударение на последний слог. В моей семье оно часто применяется. Его употребляли и бабушки, и прабабушки. Они и мы применяем его, говоря о человеке бесхребетном, нерешительном, безвольном, мягкотелом, про которого обычно говорят "ни рыба ни мясо".

Comment: Вы хотя бы регион укажите. И потом – что значит "есть ли слово"? Вы употребляете – стало быть, есть. В общелитературном языке нет.

Comment: Регион Рязань.))

Comment: В нашей семье,мой дедушка,да и папа,говаривал мне,когда я путался в чем-то простом,явном:"Ну братец.мало же ты знаешь, "сипсю да и ту не всю. "И было это у нас,на урале.

Answer (score 1):

Доступными мне словарями такое слово не фиксируется. 
Чтобы говорить о его существовании в диалектах или профессиональном жаргоне, надо иметь хотя бы несколько примеров употребления вне одной семьи. У Вас бабушки-прабабушки хотя бы из разных семей? Мамины-папины?

Comment: По отцовой линии.)))

Comment: Ну вы понимаете, что в таком случае говорить даже о диалектном слове не приходится. В лучшем случае - что-то семейное.

Comment: Спасибо!) Буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Моя бабушка тоже употребляла это слово и выражение "Сипся и та не вся". Больше ни от кого такого не слышала. Смысл слова и выражения тот же, человек бесхребетный, хилый или что-то хлипкое, не сильно стабильное, слабое (если о предмете). 
Бабушка была из Сибири.

Answer (score 0):

У меня муж так котенка называет. Говорит, что его бабушка так говорила когда чего-то было совсем-совсем мало. Это слово у него обозначает меньше чем мало. Котенок маленький, поэтому сипся:))) Так что это явно не семейное слово. Возможно что-то так называли в регионе. Муж из Каширы. Откуда была его бабушка не скажу